# Non-fixed length lookbehind workaround

Tags: c#, json, regex

Consider the following JSONs:
1st:

```
{
  "Good": {
    "a": "<good>",
    "c": "<better>",
    "e": "<best>"
  },
  "Bad": {
    "a": "<bad>",
    "c": "<worse>",
    "e": "<worst>"
  }
}
```

2nd:

```
{
  "Good": {
    "a": "<kind of good>",
    "c": "<more good>",
    "e": "<the most good>"
  },
  "Bad": {
    "a": "<a little bad>",
    "c": "<more bad>",
    "e": "<the most bad>"
  }
}
```

3rd:

```
{
  "Good": {
    "a": "<good>",
    "c": "<better>",
    "e": "<best>"
  },
  "Bad": {
    "a": "<bad>",
    "c": "<better>",
    "e": "<worst>"
  }
}
```

In all cases I've got to extract the property "c" and its value from the object "Good", make some manipulations with the value and then replace the old value with the new one.

The problem is in the object "Bad". I'm not interested in the values from that object and I'm not supposed to replace anything there.
So far I came up with that regex:

```
(?<!Bad)"c": "(<.*?>)"
```

The obvious problem is that the name of object "Bad" does not precedes property "c" right away, and symbols between might (and will) differ. And, as far as I know, lookbehind should be fixed length, so I cant just use something like that:

```
(?<!Bad.*)"c": "(<.*?>)"
```

I use regex inside C#, so I thought of just taking the first occurrence, but it is not the most reliable solution, and it still does not fixes the issue with replacement.

Talking about replacement. I thought of dynamically creating regexes to ensure that only the right occurrence would be replaced. But for the third example the trick won't work, because `"c": "(<better>)"` would match both in objects "Good" and "Bad".

Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: Why are you doing this with regex rather than with a JSON parser such as [tag:json.net], [tag:datacontractjsonserialize] or [tag:javascriptserializer]?

Comment: @dbc Well, that's a great question. It all started out very simple, and then turned into this monster; probably, I don't really need to parse it with regex. Still, if there is a correct way of doing it WITH regex, I would be happy to know about it.

Comment: You can’t parse JSON with .NET regex without balancing expressions, and that’s a lot of effort compared to using an actual JSON parser.

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan, I guess I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use JSON.NET to parse JSON. Since you know that there is a certain value in the JSON, you can use a simple code (here, just enclosing the `e` value with parentheses):

```
dynamic parsedObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
parsedObject["Good"]["e"] = $"({parsedObject["Good"]["e"]})";
var res = parsedObject.ToString();
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, seems like the direction I'm gonna use. Thank you, Wiktor!